# A table row was 3 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row

Tags: html

For school I have to make a table. It has to look like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfC0X.png)
A fragment of The code i use:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Nummers</th>
        <th>Duur</th>
        <th>Beluisteren</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Album: Nevermind</th>
        <th>Jaar: 1991</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><a href="nevermind.html#smells">Smells Like Teen Spirit</a></td>
        <td>4.37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><a href="nevermind.html#inbloom">In Bloom</a></td>
        <td>4.14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><a href="nevermind.html#come">Come As You Are</a></td>
        <td>3.39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><a href="nevermind.html#breed">Breed</a></td>
        <td>3.03</td>
    </tr>
```

II get the warning from W3C: *A table row was 3 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row*
I understand what they think I do wrong (I use 3 columns, while I have 4), but that's what I am supposed to do for the school practice.

Is there something i can change in the code so that I can do what I want without a warning from W3C?

Thanks for helping! Greetings Kim

Comment: Add a blank cell at the end of each row: `<td></td>`.

Comment: Thanks. I added an extra cell and now it works :)